# Forma correcta de comenzar un proyecto en Git

Tags: git, github

Hay un proyecto en Git el cual tengo que modificar.
Cual sería la diferencia entre :

- Hacer un fork del proyecto, luego hacerle un pull, trabajar local y luego pushearlo
- no hacer un fork, solo hacer pull, trabajar local y luego pushear

Answer (score 3):

La idea del git es que *todo son repositorios*. Así que "trabajar en local" (`git clone`) significa hacer un fork del proyecto (que sí, solo estará en tu disco duro pero es técnicamente igual que cualquier otro repositorio).

Por eso los `commits` se hacen en local (a diferencia de SVN o CVS, donde el `commit` es enviarlo al servidor original), porque estás enviando el cambio a tu "servidor" local.

En cuanto a hacer un clone en un servidor (p.ej. github) o no, depende de la situación. Obviamente si partes de un proyecto de una tercera persona conviene hacer tu propia copia para poder hacer `push` de lo que vas cambiando, sin tener que hacer `pull request` que te pueden denegar. Pero una vez que ya tienes tu repositorio bajo tu control, lo más normal es hacer nuevos cambios como `branches`.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres trabajar siempre va a terminar en master del proyecto inicial, no hay ninguna diferencia a nivel de como se trabaja.

A nivel conceptual si que hay, generalmente el uso de fork se atribuye a una bifurcación completa de un proyecto, es el punto en que diverge completamente del origen, usualmente se hace por ejemplo para actualizar proyectos que ya no son mantenidos.

Así que siendo purista, si vas a continuar el desarrollo pero sin crear un nuevo proyecto, clona el proyecto directamente y trabaja así, si por el contrario quieres bifurcarlo y hacer otro desarrollo basado en ese, es hora de hacer un fork.